# yum update impact on user or cots software

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

I understand that yum update will update all software (system and user/commercial s/w) to the latest available packages. What happens if the servers have various commercial software like Mysql, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Hadoop etc. will all these software also get upgraded to the latest version. In case certain version of say MySQL doesnt work with Hadoop or other software how do you make sure that the system doesnt run into major conflicts among the various user software due to the yum update. System or kernel software probably has less chance of conflict among each other compared to  commercial software. Of course, we need to always update Test env. prior to Prod to check issues or do a minimal yum --security update but just wondering if thats how yum behaves and how do people update the servers safely without software conflicts.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure how the enterprise packages are handled in case of an update, but for the packages that you are sure not need be updated, can be locked to the version number installed with `yum versionlock` [plugin](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/98873) after installation and in case of an update they are skipped.